# Git conflict for xcode 6.1 in storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard

How to solve conflict for git in xcode for one storyboard.

Point 1 :: In my project I m having one storyboard not multiple storyboard. Can not create multiple storyboard because project UI is 70% Done and more than 2+ developer are working on project. Xcode is not able solve conflict by its own while it solve for other files but not for storyboard.

Can any one help me to resolve this issue in better way.

Comment: Sounds nasty.  I doubt you'll want to start resolving the merge conflicts yourself, so you'll have to abandon your edit and accept the upstream versions and start again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem by putting .DS_Store file adding it in ignore folder...